# How can I filter the entire contents of a site by region?

Tags: views

I have a classifieds site that I created at http://www.gastonia.com.  I've introduced the location module, and I am using views to search by proximity after someone types in a zipcode and distance. Everything is working fine.

I now want to experiment with filtering the entire site's displayed contents - all pages, all blocks, all views, all menus, etc. When someone types in their zip code and hits submit, every item of content is filtered for them within 25 miles of their region.

I can easily do this with Views and filters, even for blocks where arguments don't work.  I also want to do this for all 770 towns in my state, which means creating views programatically.  Each would have its own page / url title like Gastonia-NC and Shelby-NC and show items accordingly.

I  have created the script to do that - loop through all 770, and everything actually works, except it's slow, to say the least. Maybe there is a better way to do this?  Note the production site does not have the location / filter implemented, just my dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use views then just use the views global filter module. This way they only enter their location only once then every other view on the site inherits this filter.